# Symbolic Link disappears after restart

Tags: macos, symlink

I'm running  Mac OS X 10.8.4

I make the following symbolic link

```
ln -s /Users/AlyssaPHacker/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

But every time I restart the computer, the symbolic link disappears and I have to create it again.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/tmp` directory is emptied when the system boots so your link is lost.

You can use the special `cron` `@reboot` entry to run your command during each boot:

```
@reboot ln -s /Users/AlyssaPHacker/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

in the crontab file - see the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/crontab)

Comment: My understanding is that `launchd` is now the preferred way to accomplish this. Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html